# A transport-level error has occurred... (Existing connection closed by the server) Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a web application which is currently running on Windows XP operating system with SQL Server 2005 database and IIS 6.0. 
Now, we are trying to upgrade it to IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2008 and SQL server 2008 database.

When I run the application then it is throwing "A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)" randomly at different database calls. 

I have verified using *"sp_who"* that only one connection which I am using is opened.

Can anyone tell me, what could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: any solution for this???

Answer (score 14):

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/spike/archive/2009/04/16/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-sending-the-request-to-the-server-provider-tcp-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host.aspx) by [Michael Aspengren](http://blogs.msdn.com/spike/default.aspx) explains the error message "A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server."

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the database is set to auto-close? This used to be the default for databases created on the older MSDE/Express edition.

```
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName SET AUTO_CLOSE OFF;
```

**More:**

The [SQL Server 2005 Express Edition Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345154(SQL.90).aspx) states:

> Features like Auto-Close and the ability to copy databases as files are enabled by default in SQL Server Express ...

I can't remember which service pack changed the default, but the New Database UI in the SP3 version of Management Studio Express defaults the `Auto Close` setting to `false`.

Comment: MSDE, yes. Which Express edition was this ever the default in?

Comment: @devstuff - works, but needs to be executed every time SQL server is started afresh. Any way to make it permanent ?

Answer (score 2):

This is an error that occurrs when connecting to database due to a lower layer network-related error that you cannot handle from Sql Server.

It would be great that the API used to conenct handled this error but AFAIK it is not. The only way to solve this is to retry connecting to the database when this error occurrs.

You should try to reconnect at least a couple of times more to get sure that the error is not persistent and if it is the case then throw the exception. My experience tells me that trying to reconnect, the 99.9% of times you will succed.

Answer (score 1):

Often, it's the database being offline/closed or the SQL Instance being restarted/offline

Answer (score 1):

In my case.  We have DELL R720, NICs are on board and PCI Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet cards.  We run into two issues.

1. Network speed is very slow for HyperV VMs.   The solution is to disable the "Virtual Machine queues" of the HyperV host Broadcom nic property windows.  It is in the Advanced tab.
2. SQL client having this transport level issue.  It only happened once in every 10-15 min.  At the same time the RDP service kick out client from time to time also.   The solution is to disable the "Large Send Offload V2" of the HyperV host Broadcom nic property windows.  It is in the Advanced tab.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `MultipleActiveResultSets=true;` set in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Transport level errors are often linked to the connection to sql server being broken ... usually network.

Timeout Expired is usually thrown when a sql query takes too long to run. Is this the scenario in your case? Like stored proc taking too much time to execute or are there are batch jobs that are executed?

Answer (score 0):

Use clearpool(urSQLconnection), along with dispose. This will clear the dirty connection. and you can open new connection.

Answer (score 0):

Got this trying to execute commands from multiple threads on one connection object in .net, that was a stupid mistake. Locking it or using a separate connection per thread fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was McAffee that was pre-installed. Can tell if it was conflict with other solutions or not. The connection was on VPN, on WiFI. Maybe this will help someone in future.